# Programmatic way to create Decimal of max of signed 32-bit float (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, decimal

## Problem Statement and Background

I am writing a function which is given string containing a single float value, e.g., '3.14159'.

What I would like to do is to evaluate whether or not this float is withing the boundaries of the a signed 32-bit float (also, a 64-bit, but let's forget about that for now).

Due to floating point precision issues, I wanted to use the `Decimal` object for comparison.

## What I am asking:

How do I create a `Decimal` with the value of the largest signed 32-bit float in it?

This will be used for comparison.

## What I have tried:

After skimming this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

... which reports that there are 23 coefficient bits, 8 exponent bits and 1 sign bit, I wrote the following code.

```
from decimal import Decimal


def is_single(value):
    d_value = Decimal(value)

    _23bit_max_bin = '1' * 23  # '11111111111111111111111'
    _23bit_max_dec = int(_23bit_max_bin, 2)  # 8388607

    _coeffient_tuple = tuple([int(d) for d in str(_23bit_max_dec)])  # (8, 3, 8, 8, 6, 0, 6)

    _exponent_bin = '1' * 8  # '11111111'
    _exponent_dec = int(_exponent_bin, 2)  # 255

    _dec_tuple = (0, _coeffient_tuple, _exponent_dec)  # (1, (8, 3, 8, 8, 6, 0, 6), 254)
    max_single_size = Decimal(_dec_tuple)  # Decimal('8.388607E+261')

    print(max_single_size)  # Decimal('8.388607E+261')

    return d_value < max_single_size


is_single('3.14159')
```

... my hope here is that I could take the max binary values for the coefficient and exponent, convert them to decimal values, and then create a `Decimal` object using the results.

The problem is that the resultant value does seem to similar to the values reported on the same wikipedia page, i.e., `8.388607E+261` (my value) is not like `1.1754942107 ×10−38` (wiki)

I feel as though I am missing something ... perhaps it is too late in the day?

## Readings:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … the boundaries of the a signed 32-bit float…

The representable numbers in `float` range from −∞ to +∞, so all finite numbers are within the range. But I suppose you want to consider the finite range of the `float` type, not the full range.

```
_23bit_max_bin = '1' * 23  # '11111111111111111111111'
_23bit_max_dec = int(_23bit_max_bin, 2)  # 8388607
```

That gives you the maximum value of the significand field of the `float` encoding, interpreted as a binary integer. That is not the maximum value of the represented significand.

Assuming the exponent field is neither all zeros nor all ones, the represented significand is the number whose binary numeral is “1” followed by “.” followed by the bits of the significand field. So the maximum significand is 1.11111111111111111111111<sub>2</sub> = 2<sup>1</sup>−2<sup>−23</sup>.

```
exponent_bin = '1' * 8  # '11111111'
```

That gives you the maximum value of the exponent field. However, the maximum value of the exponent field is used to encode infinities and NaNs, not finite numbers. The maximum value of the exponent field used for finite numbers is 11111110<sub>2</sub> (254<sub>10</sub>). Further, the represented exponent is the value of the exponent field (interpreted as a binary integer) minus 127. So the maximum exponent is 254−127 = 127.

```
_dec_tuple = (0, _coeffient_tuple, _exponent_dec)  # (1, (8, 3, 8, 8, 6, 0, 6), 254)
```

That uses 254 as an exponent of 10. The exponent in the `float` format is an exponent of 2.

The maximum finite value representable in `float` is the maximum significand multiplied by 2 to the power of the maximum exponent, so it is (2<sup>1</sup>−2<sup>−23</sup>) • 2<sup>127</sup> = 2<sup>128</sup> − 2<sup>104</sup> = 340282346638528859811704183484516925440. Let’s call that number *M*.

However, when determining whether a decimal numeral is in bounds, you should consider whether you want to consider whether:

- the number is in −*M* to +*M*, inclusive, or
- the number is in the range where normal rounding upon conversion to `float` would produce a value in −*M* to +*M*, inclusive (*i.e.*, it does not round to an infinity).

In the latter case, in round to nearest mode, the limit you want is 2<sup>128</sup> − 2<sup>104</sup> + 2<sup>103</sup> = 2<sup>128</sup> − 2<sup>103</sup> = 340282356779733661637539395458142568448, exclusive. That “half step,” 2<sup>103</sup>, toward where the next representable number would be if the exponent range kept going, is where the round-to-nearest method changes between rounding down and rounding up. In the case of a tie exactly on that point, it rounds to the number with the even significand bit, which would be upward. So you want to exclude it, hence the interval is exclusive rather than inclusive.

Generally, if the precision is *p* (the significand field has *p*−1 bits) and the exponent field has *w* bits, the exponent bias is 2<sup>*w*−1</sup>−1, the maximum exponent the same, and the greatest representable finite value is (2−2<sup>1−*p*</sup>) • 2<sup>2<sup>*w*−1</sup>−1</sup> = (1−2<sup>−*p*</sup>) • 2<sup>2<sup>*w*−1</sup></sup>.

Comment: Eric, could you explain what `2 - 2^-23`, represents? I understand the 23 as the significant bits but I am not sure why we are raising to a negative power and finding the difference of 2? Is this because of the one at the left of the period? I am also concluding from this that floating point numbers can hold much larger numbers but are less accurate.

Comment: Ahh... I see, that came from the wikipedia I referenced. Maybe I should just sit down and read the thing till I understand thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually: 3.4028234664 × 10^38

Try to look for the following numbers:

2^128 =
340282366920938463463374607431768211456

10^38 =
100000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: It is 340282346638528859811704183484516925440, not 3.4028234664 × 10^38.